# XML Numbered elements - navigating in the loop?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have here the structure of the XML file as the following (this is only a part). The individual elements are numbered, and here's my problem, and navigate these elements, such as whether   in the loop foreach if they do not have the same tags?

```
<produkty>
<kategoria>
    <nazwa>TUNIKI</nazwa>
    <produkt-1>
        <nazwa>Tunika Matita</nazwa>
        <opis>dsadasd</opis>
        <tabela_rozmiarow>xxx</tabela_rozmiarow>
        <warianty>
            <wariant-36>
                <rozmiar>36</rozmiar>
                <dostepne_kolory>
                    <element-0>
                        <nazwa_koloru>fioletowy</nazwa_koloru>
                        <strona_produktu>xxx</strona_produktu>
                        <stan_magazynowy>4</stan_magazynowy>
                        <ceny>
                            <cena_netto>45,53 PLN</cena_netto>
                            <cena_brutto>56,00 PLN</cena_brutto>
                        </ceny>
                        <zdjecia>
                            <zdjecie-1>
                                <url>xxx</url>
                            </zdjecie-1>
                            <zdjecie-2>
                                <url>xxx</url>
                            </zdjecie-2>
                        </zdjecia>
                    </element-0>
                    <element-1>
                        <nazwa_koloru>biały</nazwa_koloru>
                        <strona_produktu>xxx</strona_produktu>
                        <stan_magazynowy>(> 100)</stan_magazynowy>
                        <ceny>
                            <cena_netto>45,53 PLN</cena_netto>
                            <cena_brutto>56,00 PLN</cena_brutto>
                        </ceny>
                        <zdjecia>
                            <zdjecie-1>
                                <url>xxx</url>
                            </zdjecie-1>
                        </zdjecia>
                    </element-1>
                </dostepne_kolory>
            </wariant-36>
        </warianty>
    </produkt-1>
```

I want to do something like this:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('URL_FILE');
 foreach ($xml->kategoria as $cat) {
   foreach ($cat->produkt as $prod) {
      ...
   }
 }
```

But if the tags  are as `<produkt-1> <produkt-2> ... <produkt-n>` how can I do to read this foreach loop?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't get the exact problem you face (what is a name tag, which loop?!). Could you please clarify what you actually want to achieve? Anyways, if you want to compare to a dynamic node name, you might want to do something like `*[name(.) = 'produkt-1']`

Comment: If your `produkt*` elements represent the same type of information than the issue is that the XML document is not well made. If you want to distinguish your `produkt` elements it should be as a attribute and not as part of the element name unless it represents different information.